# Passing UIViewController reference to the next View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Imagine that im making a app for "Bed Bath and Beyound".
Each section will have a custom view (one for Bed, one for Bath and one for beyond). Once the user click a product he will be taken to a "object detail" view...
I notice that in my app i could make a single view to handle all the "object details", but when the user hits "back" i have to return him to the correct view...

I thought that I could just create a `@property (strong,readwrite) UIViewController *controllerToReturn;` and right before pushing the "object detail" view I could do like `objectView.controllerToReturn = self` but its not working... I keep getting a

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Can anyone help?

Notes: I did `@synthesize controllerToReturn;`

Comment: Why are you not using an NSNavigationController ?

Comment: @Pétur because the user goes to the "object detail" view by rotating the device to the landscape position...

Comment: Listen for a UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and take action using the navigation controller.

Comment: @Pétur the problem is not "listening to rotation"... i need help storing the reference for the current view and pushing it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need that. If you use a UINavigationBar with a push segue, the 'Back' button will segue back to one of the 3 controllers that led to this detail view.

Another option, say you use a modal segue, add an action to a 'Cancel' button for instance that looks like :

```
- (IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT :**

If you need to detect rotations :

In your App delegate (in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) write

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

And then, to detect that you rotated back to portrait :

```
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {

       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }
```

Comment: The user is taken to the "object detail" view by rotating the device to the landscape position...

Comment: So you want to detect that the user rotated back to portrait orientation and then go back to your main view ?

Comment: first of all tks for the help! The rotation part i got working... what i don't have working is "going back" to the initial view... i imagine that passing the reference to the "object detail" view and then "pushing it back" would work... but apparently its not...